# Show that a convergent sequence exists within any uncountable set of reals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Assume $A$ is an uncountable set of reals, show there exists a convergent sequence $a_n$ such that $(\forall n \ a_n\in A) \land (\forall n,m \ n\neq m\implies a_n\neq a_m)$

Please check the validity of my proof:

The equistence of such a sequence implies that there is a point $a$ in $A$ such that in any neighbour-hood around $a$, there is infinitely many points within it.

Assume for a contradiction, the contrary, that is assume: for every point in $a$ there is a neighbour-hood around $a$ in which only finitely many points lie within.

Now we will develop a method to count the elements of $A$ via the above assumption, finishing our proof by contradiction. Chose any element say $v_0$, by the assumption choose a neighbourbood which contains finitely many other points (such that $v_0$ is not the smallest or largest element of this neighbourhood.). Call this set $V_0$. Define $v_{-1}:=\text{min}(V_0)$ and $v_{1}:=\text{max}(V_0)$, find a suitable neighbourhood for points $v_1$ and $v_2$ and inductively continue.

The countably many finite sets $\cdots,V_{-2},V_{-1},V_0,V_1,V_2,\cdots$ union to make another countable set $V$. It is easy to prove $A=V$. $\square$

**NEW CLEANER PROOF TO CHECK:**

Notice that if there exists a neighbourhood with infinitely many elements from $A$, then the desired sequence exists by Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Assume that such a neighbourhood does not exist, chose any $v\in A$, notice the amount of $a\in A$ and $a\in V_1=(v-1,v+1)$ is finite, $V_2=(v-2,v+2)/V_1$ is finite, and generally $V_n=(v-n,v+n)/V_{n-1}$ is finite. The union of countably many finite $V_n$ is countable, the obvious bijection between $A$ and $V=V_1\cup V_2\cup\cdots$ proves $A$ is countable, we have our contradiction.

Comment: How do you prove that if any point has a neighborhood with finitely many points from $A$, then $(v - 1, v + 1)$ has finitely many points from $A$?

Comment: @mihaild You can actually prove that in general (v-k,v+k) has finitely many points pretty easily. Assume the contrary, this means there is some bounded set J of all elements j such that (v-j,v+j) is finite, consider either point v+sup(J) or v-sup(J), this would be a point that by definition has no neighbourhood with finitely many points, a contradiction.
(let me know if this checks out)

Comment: Here is an even simpler proof. For each natural number $n$, consider the subset $A_n = [-n,n] \cap A$. Case 1: If $A_n$ is infinite for some $n$ then, by the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $A_n$ has a convergent sequence, hence $A$ does. Case 2: If $A_n$ is finite for all $n$ then $A$ is countable.

Comment: @LeeMosher Very nice much better way of handling the sets

Comment: An alternative argument using @LeeMosher 's idea. At least one of the intervals $[n,n+1)$ must contain infinitely many elements of $A$.

Comment: In the new cleaner proof, there's no need to include $/V_{n-1}$ in the definition of $V_n$. The union of countably many finite sets is countable. (There's also no need to choose $v\in V$; simply letting the $n$th interval be $(-n,n)$ is enough.)

Comment: @GregMartin Yeah I realized I didn't need to remove the previous set but did it because it made the idea clearer in my head. Thanks for the help.